# Links to the 3D House Builder and Blue Angle website in MIX11?

Tags: silverlight-5.0

Anyone know where I can find these two awesome websites demonstrated in MIX11?

Thanks heaps!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They said they're going to release the application with full source code on their site this month.

Answer (score 2):

You can download the source from here:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/3D-Housebuilder-demo-from-def4af04